# Convert array of objects to object using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have an array of objects that i need to convert to a single object.
ex:need to convert

```
var data=[
  {
    "name": "EMPRESA",
    "value": "CMIP"
  },
  {
    "name": "DSP_DIRECAO",
    "value": "CMIP@040@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "name": "DSP_DEPT",
    "value": "CMIP@040@1900-01-01@42@1900-01-01"
  },
```

...
    ]

to

```
   {
    "EMPRESA": "CLCA",
    "DSP_DIRECAO": "CLCA@100@1900-01-01",
    "DSP_DEPT": "CLCA@100@1900-01-01@100@1900-01-01",
    ...
  }
```

Turn data[x][name] to propertie and data[x][value]  to atribute value
Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the code you've tried. The can simply be done by looping over array elements and adding key-value pairs to the object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Doesn't use LoDash, but a straight forward `reduce()`

```
var obj = data.reduce( (a,b) => {
    return a[b.name] = b.value, a;
}, {});
```

```js
var data=[
  {
    "name": "EMPRESA",
    "value": "CMIP"
  },
  {
    "name": "DSP_DIRECAO",
    "value": "CMIP@040@1900-01-01"
  },
  {
    "name": "DSP_DEPT",
    "value": "CMIP@040@1900-01-01@42@1900-01-01"
  }
]

var obj = data.reduce( (a,b) => {
    return a[b.name] = b.value, a;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Doing the same in LoDash would be something like

```
var obj = _.transform(data, (a,b) => {
    return a[b.name] = b.value, a;
},{});
```

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. Kudos!

Comment: Nice use of comma operator

Comment: The transform method doesn't need to return the accumulator like reduce does. You can do something like: `const output = _.transform(data, (a, b) => a[b.name] = b.value, {});`

Answer (score 2):

On lodash 4.15,

```
_.chain(data).keyBy("name").mapValues("value").value()
```

On lodash 3.10,

```
_.chain(data).indexBy("name").mapValues("value").value()
```

Comment: im using lodash 3.10 ... QuadTable.js:352 Uncaught TypeError: _.chain(...).keyBy is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
var newObj = {}
var data = [{
    "name": "EMPRESA",
    "value": "CMIP"
}, {
    "name": "DSP_DIRECAO",
    "value": "CMIP@040@1900-01-01"
}, {
    "name": "DSP_DEPT",
    "value": "CMIP@040@1900-01-01@42@1900-01-01"
}]
data.forEach(function(d) {
    newObj[d.name] = d.value
})
```